# FFmpeg's common filter "v360" missing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, virtual-reality

I'm trying to convert a 180° fisheye video to a normal/regular video using the [`v360` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360) of [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

This is the command I tried:
`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "v360=input=fisheye:output=flat:iv_fov=180:v_fov=90" out.mp4`

But the output says clearly `No such filter: 'v360'`, although [v360](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360) is a common filter listed in docs and other filters I used before worked just fine. I tried updating/reinstalling and looking for solutions, not fixing it.

Why is the filter missing? How can I debug this? Should I doe the task using another program entirely?

Command output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-09-11T14:18:33.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:48.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26056 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 2160x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 25924 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-09-11T14:18:33.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-09-11T14:18:33.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55ee57567340] No such filter: 'v360'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Output of `ffmpeg -filters` if needed (didn't fit in question's char limit): https://hastebin.com/eyebefuzez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your ffmpeg is too old

You need at least version 4.3 to use the v360 filter (see [`Changelog`](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/HEAD:/Changelog)). For Linux you can [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a new version or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) it yourself.

The online documentation is synced with the latest code (git master branch). So releases may not have features mentioned in the online documentation. Refer to your locally installed documentation if you are stuck using an old release: `man ffmpeg-filters`